# How to do multiline non-rectangular deletion?

Tags: multiple-lines, selection

Here is a problem I am able to solve in Sublime in seconds but has me stumped in Vim:

Given text like this:

```
bob@bobshop.com Bob Potato
peter@petershop.co.uk Peter Carrot
thomas.cucumber@thomasstore.org Thomas Cucumber
```

I would like to delete either all the names in one go, and then the email addresses, or all the email addresses and then the names.

I'm hoping there is a way that doesn't require 10th Dan Regex skills?

Comment: Just wondering: is there a reason you need to delete them in a specific order?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble no, like I said either order. Or do you mean why in one lot, and then another? If the latter, it's so I can paste them into the correct columns of a spreadsheet. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete all emails first:

`vip:norm! dW`

- `vip` select paragraph
- `:norm! dW` execute normal mode commands: delete WORD

Then you end up having only names -- delete them as usual I guess?

To delete all names first:

`vip:norm! WD`

- `vip` select paragraph
- `:norm! WD` execute normal mode commands: move cursor 1 WORD and delete to the end of line.

Comment: With no visual mode: `:%norm WD` and `:%norm dt x`

Answer (score 1):

1st Dan needed to delete the names. The delimiter is the first space. So delete everything from the first space to end of line:

```
s/ .*$//
```

To delete the emails, a 2nd Dan is needed. Delete any non-space and the first space from the beginning of the line:

```
s/^[^ ]* //
```

Note: This answer assumes, that the delimiter is a single space character. If the delimiter between the email and the name is a `<tab>` or multiple spaces or any combination of it, we have to move to the 3rd Dan:

```
s/\s.*$//
```

This deletes from the first whitespace (be it a space or a tab) till the end of line.

```
s/^\S*\s\+//
```

This deletes from the beginning of the line (`^`) all non-whitespace characters (`\S*`) including the following one or more whitespaces (`\s\+`).

See `:help /\s`, `:help /^` and `:help /\+`.

Now ranges:

The simplest case is if you want to act on the entire file, just use `%` like:

```
:%s/ .*$//
```

If it is only a part of the file, the easiest way is to visually select the lines and then hit `:` and enter one of the substitution commands from above.

Comment: Had me laughing with the regex belts :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that would be to use a macro.

Given you are on the 1st line 1st col:

```
" To delete the emails:
qa0dWjq2@a

" To delete the names:
qa0ElDjq2@a
```

Though I would admit that it's far from being as intuitive as Sublime or VScode with the multi cursors.

---

Or, as you mentioned, we can use holy regex:

```
" To delete the emails:
s/^\S\+//g

" To delete the names:
s/^\S\zs\s.*$//g
```

---

Or, you could use the `norm` command:

```
" To delete the emails:
vip:norm!dW

" To delete the names:
vip:norm!ElD
```